Duplicate Document Number and Different Revisions, would like latest revision for each document
I have a list of document numbers (column A) and the associated revisions (column B). I am trying to look up a document number and return the latest revision of the document.

The document number I am referencing is in cell C1.
I can not have helper columns.

I have tried
INDEX(A:B,MATCH(C1,A:A,0),2)

But only get the first instance.
Your help will be much appreciated.

Do a reverse lookup: =LET(α, A2:A7, δ, UNIQUE(α), HSTACK(δ, XLOOKUP(δ,α,B2:B7,,,-1))) or --> =INDEX(B$2:B$7,MATCH(C1,A$2:A$7,1))
